# How do you extract all the elements of tuple from for loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tuples, combinations

I am trying to solve combinations(nCr) problem. I have the following numbers `[1,2,3,4]`. The code needs to produce all the possible combinations(4C2): `(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4)`. Here is the code:

```py
import itertools
from math import factorial

def calc_combin(n, r):
    return factorial(n) // factorial(r) // factorial(n-r)

lines=calc_combin(4,2) #4C2

b_list = list(range(1,5))
combinations = itertools.combinations(b_list,2)

c_list=[]

for i_c in range(0,lines):
    c_list.append([])

for c in combinations:
    c                 #tuple that has all the combinations
    c_listi = list(c) #converting tuple "c" to list "c_listi"
    print(c_listi)
```

This is the output:

```
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[3, 4]
```

Now I want the output values to be stored outside the for loop. without overwriting the previous values.

Is there a way to extract all the tuple(`c`) elements outside the for-loop? If not how do you extract it from list variable(`c_listi`) outside the for-loop?

Comment: Try converting the iterator to a list directly: `list(itertools.combinations(...))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assign the contents of `itertools.combinations` to a variable as a list, you can reuse it as many times as you like:

```
cs = list(itertools.combinations(b_list,2))
```

If you need the contents to be lists, instead of tuples:

```
cs = [list(t) for t in itertools.combinations(b_list,2)]
```

After either, you can use and reuse `cs` as often as you like.